# Why does Ruby String#split not treat consecutive trailing delimiters as separate entities?

Tags: ruby, string

I'm reading from a government text file in which $ is used as the delimiter, but I don't think  delimiter character matters...

So this is expected:

```
'a$b$c$d'.split('$')
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

In the datafiles I'm working with, the column headers row (the first line) are uniformly filled in, i.e. there is no empty header, as in:

```
'a$b$$d'
# or: 
'a$b$c$'
```

However, each row may have consecutive trailing delimiters such as:

```
"w$x$$\r\n"
```

Usually, I read each line and **chomp** it. But this causes String#split to treat the final two delimiters as one column:

```
"w$x$$\r\n".chomp.split('$')
# => ["w", "x"]
```

Not doing the chomp gets me the desired result, though I should chomp the last element:

```
"w$x$$\r\n".split('$')
# => ["w", "x", "", "\r\n"]
```

So either I have to:

- chomp the line **if** the final non-newline characters are NOT consecutive delimiters
- preserve the newline, do the split, and then chomp the final element IF the final characters are consecutive delimiter

This seems really awkward...am I missing something here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to pass a negative value as the second parameter to `split`. This prevents it from suppressing trailing null fields:

```
"w$x$$\r\n".chomp.split('$', -1)
# => ["w", "x", "", ""]
```

See [the docs on `split`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/String#split-instance_method).

Comment: Thanks...for the record, the docs is where I first went, but I saw the pseudoname "limit" for the second parameter, my mind decided to shut itself off and not read through to see all the options besides positive numbers entailed. Thanks!