# ruby string split with terminal strings empty

Tags: ruby

If I define a string with nulls

```
string = "a,b,,c,d,e,f,,"
```

then

```
string.split(',')
  => ["a", "b", "", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

The empty string between "b" and "c" is accounted for, but the two at the end have been lost.  How can I split a string and preserve those trailing empty strings in the returned array?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to say:

```
string.split(',',-1)
```

to avoid omitting the trailing blanks.

per [Why does Ruby String#split not treat consecutive trailing delimiters as separate entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604369/why-does-ruby-stringsplit-not-treat-consecutive-trailing-delimiters-as-separate)

The second parameter is the "limit" parameter, documented at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-split as follows:

> If the "limit" parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are
>   suppressed. If limit is a positive number, at most that number of
>   fields will be returned (if limit is 1, the entire string is returned
>   as the only entry in an array). If negative, there is no limit to the
>   number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not
>   suppressed.