# Splitting into empty substrings

Tags: ruby, string, split

I get this result (notice that the first `""` is for the preceding empty match):

```
"babab".split("b")
# => ["", "a", "a"]
```

By replacing `"a"` with an empty string in the input above as follows,

```
"bbb".split("b")
```

I expected to get the following result:

```
["", "", ""]
```

But in reality, I get:

```
[]
```

What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Here is good corresponding helpful explanation for above, https://stackoverflow.com/q/19917499/10522579

Comment: @ray: this explanation is citing the same documentation :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, but your csv related example made more sense for _why_ rather than _how_ :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Logic is described [in the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-split):

> If the `limit` parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed.

Trailing empty fields are removed, but not leading ones.

---

If, by any chance, what you were asking is "yeah, but where's the logic in *that*?", then imagine we're parsing some CSV.

```
fname,sname,id,email,status
,,1,sergio@example.com,
```

We *want* the first two position to remain empty (rather than be removed and have fname become 1 and sname - sergio@example.com).

We care less about trailing empty fields. Removed or kept, they don't shift data.

Comment: Yes, doc also explains further that _If negative, there is no limit to the number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not suppressed_. So `split("b", -1)` will work.

Comment: @Sergio I am not asking about preceding empty fields, which I understand. And I had previously read the part you cited, but my interpretation of "trailing null fields" is probably different from yours. By "null", I imagined where there is no more matches, which I am actually not clear about, but may be that is wrong. Can you expand on what a "trailing null field" is?

Comment: Okay, I think I got what "trailing null fields" mean. First of all, "null" should be interpreted as empty string. Second, "trailing" should mean "consecutive things at the end of the result array." The document is misleading.

Comment: @sawa: I think they mean those zero-length empty strings, but in 20 minutes of reading of reading ruby, c and c++ sources, I am not able to pin it to a line of code.

Comment: @sawa: yes, that's what "trailing" means :)